# Selenium, verfiy that field formats correctly

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium and was hoping to get some help with this. Imagine that we have a box in which the user can write; I need to assert that the text field correctly formats the field for 1000000.00 = $1,000,000.00
I'm trying to use selenium and java to verify this. The field is represented by the html below.

```
<div id="req8">
<h2>Test #8</h2>
<input id="req8input" type="text" value="Type Number Here">
</div>
```

How would I go about this in Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) to get the correct text format for your value and then you can do an assert on the existing text value of the field. You can make the pattern specific to the locale as well. There are various other options. Something like this should work.

```
String value=""1000000.00""
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
WebElement webElement= driver.findElement(By.ById("req8input"));
webElement.sendKeys("100);
assertEquals(output, webElement.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("req8input"));
```

To set the value of a text box:

```
el.sendKeys("1000000");
```

To read back the value:

```
String val = el.getAttribute("value");
```

To compare it:

```
assertEquals("$1,000,000.00", val);
```

Seeing as you said you are new to Selenium, this is probably going to lead to *huge* amount of questions. So to answer your next question(s): start with the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)!

Comment: OP seems to be asking regarding **formatting of value** not send, get and assert value. What if 1000000 is not hardcoded? In that scenario your assert is gonna fail anyhow.

Comment: @VivekSingh OP only said "new to selenium" and "some help", and did not explicitly clarify any more beyond that. I was actually considering flagging the question as too broad. You are of course free to disagree and downvote me.